# Getting hilighting in a vim color file

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to edit my colour scheme in vim, and I remember when I was using Fedora I could get an easy preview of the colour when I changed it.

If I had a line like:

```
let ColourAssignment['String']          = {"GUIFG": 'LightYellow', "CTERMFG": '118'}
```

The word `ColourAssignment` would get hilighted as the colour I set `'string'` to.

I'm using a mac now, but I have the same plugins and .vimrc as I had when using fedora.

Does anyone know what I need to set, or what plugin I could use to get this behavior again?

Comment: What version of vim were you using before and now?

Comment: I believe I was using 7.3 for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact solution I was looking for, it turns out there is a syntax file included with the bandit colour scheme that allows for this functionality.

The repository is:
https://github.com/vim-scripts/bandit.vim

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you ask for (it highlights the colors themselves, not the highlight group name), but I can highly recommend the [Colorizer plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3567).

Comment: This plugin would be super useful for CSS/Web stuff. Unfortunately I'm hoping to get the colour based off the ctermfg number.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want `:hi String guifg=LightYellow ctermfg=118` and `:syn match String /ColourAssignment/`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there are online Vim colorscheme editors, such as:

- http://bytefluent.com/vivify/
- http://www.vimtax.com/